# IOError when executing a Python script from another Python script

Tags: python

I am a newbie to Python scripting and stuck with an issue which i am not able to figure out.
Checked a lot of posts on SO but could not find a satisfactory solution to my problem.
Here is my python code.

My requirement is that I have existing python script EXECUTE.py which accepts the EXECUTESQL.cfg as an argument from the command line.
EXECUTESQL.cfg contains the .SQL which i need to execute when the EXECUTE.py is called.
Currently i can run the script with this command and its running without any issue.

```
$PYTHON3_EXEC EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg
```

Now i want to call the above command from another python script which i tried to do as below but not able to execute.

```
with open("EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg") as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg", 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

Whenever i execute i get the following error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg'
```

Not sure why i am getting this as i am pretty sure both EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg are there in the directory. 
Can anobody help me with the problem and how to resolve it

Thanks

Vikeng21

Answer (score 0):

The `open` function opens 1 file. So when you do `open("EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg")`, it tries to open a file called `"EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg"`, which of course, does not exist. To open multiple files, you need to use multiple `open` statements like this:

```
with open("EXECUTE.py") as f1, open("EXECUTESQL.cfg") as f2:
```

But you should not use `compile` and `exec` when all you want to do is run another script. For that, look at the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks Jayanth. I tried with subprocess module also subprocess.call("EXECUTE.py EXECUTESQL.cfg") but could not get it working

Comment: That's not how you use the `subprocess` module. Please read the documentation and if you have a different problem related to that, then you should ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a solution to my problem and run the script. Hope it helps someone.

```
import sys
import os
import EXECUTE

EXECUTE.executeSQL('EXECUTESQL.cfg', None)
```